# Can MOTODEV studio be used to develop apps for any phone?

Tags: android, motodev-studio

I'm starting with android app development, I have a motorola atrix phone and recently I've read about the existence of the MOTODEV studio. I't has very useful features and I'd like to use it but I don't know, the name makes me fear that that apps developed in MOTODV studio are optimized for motorola phones and I don't know if the apps would run without concern in any phone.

So, can I use MOTODEV studio to develop apps for any phone without concern?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motodev is "just" Eclipse + ADT + some Motorola stuff. You can use it to write for any android device if you find Motodev better. You can also not use it even if you target Motorola devices only. It is just IDE.

Comment: Thanks. And for the comments below I better use standar Android SDK

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just a bundle of eclipse plugins. However it is a dead-end product, as from what I understand, most if not all of the team who worked on it was laid off.

Comment: Is this true? how do you know this?

Comment: But this just mean the people that used to de workimg on it is not anymore doing it isn't it? I mean there is other people working ot it or is it over?

Comment: From the sounds of it, the good bits from MotoDev may eventually wind up being integrated with the standard android tools. I wouldn't expect any more releases - if they do, great. But I'd get used to using the standard tools if I were you.

Comment: Yep, it seems like I better use the standard Android SDK. Thanks!!